# Software to draw maps based on Earth

Tags: mapping

I am looking for a tool to sketch changes to Earth. It should start with a geoid or an Earth model, rise/lower/flood selected areas. "Heal" boardersk: if an island is added in an ocean height shouldn't abruptly change from 0 $m$ to $-$1000 $m$. It should also measure distances between points, allow labeling and export maps of selected images as raster graphics (jpg image).

So far I could do two things:

1. Start with Google Earth, prepare necessary shapes using flooding, paste results as layers in Gimp/Photoshop [fast and ugly]
2. Import data in Matlab, define rules for modified regions, export [manual rule definitions is slow, no way to smart select, drag and drop regions]

What is the standard approach to do this? For instance, how people display flood plains, draft a channel or a new island project?

---

Windows/Mac/Linux/doesn't_matter? Windows preferred, Linux is OK. 
GUI or also command line? GUI, or GUI+CLI batching. CLI only is undesired.
Go you want to use a GIS? I didn't know about GIS. Looking into in.

Comment: Could you specify: Windows/Mac/Linux/doesn't_matter; GUI or also command line? Are you familiar with command line tools and netCDF files? You want some generic solution and don't want to use a GIS? If the usage of a GIS is fine, I would suggest to ask the question at [GIS.SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What I would do (since I don't have GIS experience): (a) download a land elevation data set as netCDF file (e.g. a global product like [GMTED2010](http://www.temis.nl/data/gmted2010/)) and (b) plot only data with an elevation above X m elevation (X m is my water level rise). However, this approach is not necessarily correct because humans build stuff like dikes ... . For the plotting I would use a tool/language of my choice: [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/) or [R](https://www.r-project.org/). Processing of the netCDF file could be done via [cdo](https://www.mpimet.mpg.de/cdo/).

Comment: My suggestion includes a lot of hand work! Therefore, I post it only as a comment and not as an answer. Adding islands etc. I would do in R oder Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common software for creating and modifying maps is ArcGIS (commercial but you can get free trial for a month) or QGIS (open source).

Comment: Could you specify how it works in ArcGIS (particularly, if and which toolboxes are needed) or QGIS?

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of "we don't recommend software" responses.